# particular prominent yticklabels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Since the paraview legends look horrible when they appear inside a latex document, I want to replace them using Python's matplotlib and Nico's [matplotlib2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz) package.

So I have compiled a python script [matplotlib4colorbars](https://github.com/highlando/matplotlib4colorbars/blob/master/colobar.py), that produces a tikz file, which can then be included in a tex document. The tex part in a single file reads (you will have to download the included image [img1.png](https://github.com/highlando/matplotlib4colorbars/blob/master/img1.png) to produce the output)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%opening
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \newlength\figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth
    \setlength\figureheight{8.5cm}
    \setlength\figurewidth{2cm}
%   \input{colorbar.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
title={$\mathbf{v_x}$},
xmin=0, xmax=0.07635,
ymin=-0.247, ymax=1.28,
axis on top,
scaled x ticks=false,
xtick={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight
]
\addplot graphics [includegraphics cmd=\pgfimage,xmin=0, xmax=0.07635, ymin=-0.247, ymax=1.28] {img1.png};
\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:13,1.28)--(axis cs:13,1.28);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:0.07635,13)--(axis cs:0.07635,13);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:13,-0.247)--(axis cs:13,-0.247);

\path [draw=black, fill opacity=0] (axis cs:0,13)--(axis cs:0,13);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and it produces [image], which I find more attractive than the paraview legend [image]

**However**, I could not reproduce the prominent `yticklabels`. So the question is, how to make that the pgfplot has the margin points as labels? And, how to make these margin labels a bit larger than the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the feature of adding extra ticks. Include the key `extra y ticks={<ymin>, <ymax>}` where you can manually write the values `<ymin>` and `<ymax>` to the `axis` environment. You can also use `extra y ticks={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}` since you have already explicitly specified the limits `ymin` and `ymax` in the `axis` environment keys.

To make the extra ticklabels larger than the other ticklabels, specify a style with `every extra y tick/.style={font=\large}`.

So the `axis` environment should be something like

```
\begin{axis}[
title={$\mathbf{v_x}$},
xmin=0, xmax=0.07635,
ymin=-0.247, ymax=1.28,
axis on top,
scaled x ticks=false,
xtick={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
extra y ticks={
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}
},
% alternatively
% extra y ticks={-0.247, 1.28},
every extra y tick/.style={
    font=\large,
    tick style=transparent, % avoid tick marks overlapping axis lines
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    precision=3
},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight
]
```

Which gives the output

[image: Extra ticks.]

This causes the ticklabels to be very tight, so a possibility is to include  `yticklabel pos=right` in the style `every extra y tick/.style`.

```
\begin{axis}[
title={$\mathbf{v_x}$},
xmin=0, xmax=0.07635,
ymin=-0.247, ymax=1.28,
axis on top,
scaled x ticks=false,
xtick={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
extra y ticks={
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}
},
% alternatively
% extra y ticks={-0.247, 1.28},
every extra y tick/.style={
    font=\large,
    tick style=transparent, % avoid tick marks overlapping axis lines
    yticklabel pos=right,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    precision=3
},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight
]
```

This gives the output

[image: Extra ticks on the right side.]

If you want the bigger numbers on the left side, simply include

```
yticklabel pos=right,
every extra y tick/.style={
    font=\large,
    tick style=transparent, % avoid tick marks overlapping axis lines
    yticklabel pos=left,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    precision=3
}
```

[image: Extra ticks on the left side, normal ticks on the right side.]