# Y-tick labels on the right side, y-axis label on the left

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

Is there a way to only move the y-tick labels to the right? The option `yticklabel pos=right` automatically moves the axis-label, too.

Here a MWE of how the axis-label is also moved:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\scaling}{0.5}
        \pgfplotsset{
            myaxis/.style={
                width={\scaling\textwidth},
                height={\scaling\textwidth/1.61803398875},
            },
        }
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            myaxis,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ymin=1e-6,
            ymax=1e12,
            xmin=-4,
            xmax=4,
            scale only axis,
            ytick={1e-5,1e2,1e9},
            yticklabels={$10^{-5}$,$10^2$,$10^{9}$},
            yticklabel pos=right
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!70!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x))};
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!30!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x*x))};
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question. It might help you. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165151/particular-prominent-yticklabels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to adjust the label positioning manually.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} %
        \newcommand{\scaling}{0.5}
        \pgfplotsset{ %
            myaxis/.style={ %
                width={\scaling\textwidth}, %
                height={\scaling\textwidth/1.61803398875}, %
            }, 
        } %
        %  
        \pgfplotsset{every axis y label/.append style={yshift=7.75cm}}  %adjust the position with yshift           
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[ %
            myaxis, %
            xlabel={$x$}, %
            ylabel={$y$}, %
            ymin=1e-6, %
            ymax=1e12, %
            xmin=-4, %
            xmax=4, %
            scale only axis,
            ytick={1e-5,1e2,1e9},
            yticklabels={$10^{-5}$,$10^2$,$10^{9}$},
            yticklabel pos=right
        ] %
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!70!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x))};
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!30!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x*x))};
        \end{semilogyaxis} %
    \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since both answers involve some manual tweaking I will take this one, as is does not require `clip=false` .

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to disable the axis label via `ylabel={}` then add a node for y label on the left side. `clip=false` is required, though.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% General Setup

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Document

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} %
        \newcommand{\scaling}{0.5}
        \pgfplotsset{ %
            myaxis/.style={ %
                width={\scaling\textwidth}, %
                height={\scaling\textwidth/1.61803398875}, %
            }, 
        } %
        %               
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[ %
            myaxis, %
            xlabel={$x$}, %
            ylabel={$y$}, %
            ymin=1e-6, %
            ymax=1e12, %
            xmin=-4, %
            xmax=4, %
            scale only axis,
            ytick={1e-5,1e2,1e9},
            yticklabels={$10^{-5}$,$10^2$,$10^{9}$},
            yticklabel pos=right,ylabel={},
            clip=false,
        ] %
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!70!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x))};
        \addplot[very thick,color=blue!30!green!80,samples=500,domain=-4:4] {abs(1/(1+x*x))};
         \node[rotate=90] () at (axis cs: -5,1000) {$y$};
        \end{semilogyaxis} %
    \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{document}
```